# Flutter BLoC et workmanager : how to make unique repositories initialisation pattern?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-workmanager

I use the **BLoC**, and **workmanager** libraries.

Actually, the code runs fine. But, looks like smell code.

My problem :
I have to initialise all my repositories for the **MultiRepositoryProvider** which wraps my **MainApp()** widget. At this point, basic stuff.

```dart
void main() async {
 
  final RepositoryOne repoOne = RepositoryOne();
  final RepositoryTwo repoTwo = RepositoryTwo();

  runApp(
    MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => repoOne,
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => repoTwo,
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

But, when I declare a job for my workmanager, I have to reinitialise some of these repositories.

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case 'synchronize':
          final RepositoryOne repoOne = RepositoryOne();
          final RepositoryTwo repoTwo = RepositoryTwo();
        
            List<int> result = await repoOne.synchronize();
            if (result.isNotEmpty) {
             await repoTwo.doThings(result);
            }
        break;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

I tried several things to export in the same place the repository initialisation, but no success...

Does somebody have an idea **to not duplicate** repositories initialisation?

**Solution chosen**

I get rid of a service locator library to do this.

What I've done :

```dart
late RepositoryOne repoOne;
late RepositoryTwo repoTwo;
late RepositoryThree repoThree;
late RepositoryFour repoFour;

void initDependenciesStuff() {
  repoOne = RepositoryOne();
  repoTwo = RepositoryTwo();
}

void initAnotherDependenciesStuff() {
  repoThree = RepositoryThree();
  repoFour = RepositoryFour();
}

void main() {
  initDependenciesStuff();
  initAnotherDependenciesStuff();

  runApp(
    MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => repoOne,
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => repoTwo,
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => repoThree,
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => repoFour,
        ),

      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}


@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case 'firstThing':
        initDependenciesStuff();

        List<int> stuff = repoOne.fetchStuff();
        await repoTwo.editStuffDatabase(stuff);
       
        return Future.value(true);
      case 'secondThing':
        initAnotherDependenciesStuff();

        List<int> updatedStuff = repoFour.updateStuff();
        await repoThree.editStuffDatabase(updatedStuff);

        return Future.value(true);
      case 'thirdThing':
        initDependenciesStuff();
        initAnotherDependenciesStuff();

        // Another stuffs to do

        return Future.value(true);
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: what is going wrong here?  error or what?

Comment: I mean no success in way I don't know how to do that. I don't want to duplicate the repositories initialisation code, it's my main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) callbackDispatcher is the top level function.

so the best way to provide the same class instance in different app places is using dependency injection or service locator e.g. [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable) or  [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it).

for `get_it` it will something like this. some where in main:

```
import 'package:app.taletwist/injection_container.dart' as di;

  await di.init();
  runApp(..);
```

then in injection_container.dart:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
  sl
    ..registerSingleton(RepositoryOne())
    ..registerSingleton(RepositoryTwo())
}
```

and then wherenever you need it:

```
  runApp(
    MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => sl<RepositoryOne>(),
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => sl<RepositoryTwo>(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```

or

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case 'synchronize':
          final repoOne = sl<RepositoryOne>();
          final repoTwo = sl<RepositoryTwo>();
        
            List<int> result = await repoOne.synchronize();
            if (result.isNotEmpty) {
             await repoTwo.doThings(result);
            }
        break;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: If app is closed, this mechanism works even if "await di.init();" is not called?

Comment: I think yes, but it should be checked. these instances are created in a lazy way and they should be reinstantiated if they don't exist

Comment: I doubt because the top level function doesn't call main(). I will checking that, and let you know what I found :)

Comment: then you could try pass repos in the function:
Workmanager().initialize(
() => callbackDispatcher.call(sl<RepositoryOne>(), sl<RepositoryTwo>()),..

where function require repos void callbackDispatcher(RepositoryOne repoOne, RepositoryTwo repoTwo). anyway all this should be checked :)

Comment: So, I tried and it works. But I'm a bit annoyed to use a service locator library just to do that. I thought that bloc library can provide an API to get those dependencies easily, because under the hood I think the mechanism remains the same as Get_It but with "context" (with the .read<MyRepositoryOne>()).  Like exporting the MultiBlocProvider outside the main to use it like get_it. I accept your solution btw.

Comment: Last things : into callbackDispatcher() you have to call the repositories initialisation ! Can you edit your example please? (doc: The workmanager runs on a separate isolate from the main flutter isolate. Ensure to initialize all dependencies inside the Workmanager().executeTask.)

Comment: thanks! but what do you mean: you have to call the repositories initialisation ?
what exactly should be in callbackDispatcher()?

Comment: A lot of repositories should be initialised to make workmanager work in isolation! (db, http, repos, config, ...).

Comment: I edit my implementation above.